# Declaring instance variables in iOS - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, variables, instance

Ok, I've read a lot around these days about this topic and I alwyas get confused because the answers is different every search I make.

I need to know the best way to declare instance variables in iOS. So far I know I should only declare them inside .m file and leave .h clean. But I can't do it: the compiler gives me compilation erros.

Here is some code from .m only.

```
@interface UIDesign ()

// .m file
{
    NSString *test2 = @"test2";
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) int privateInt;

@end

@implementation UIDesign
{
    NSString *test1 = @"test1";
}
```

Both strings are declared incorrectly and I don't know why. The compiler says: **expected ';' at end of declaration list**.

**So the question is: how can I declare instance variables? I will only need them inside the class.**

Comment: MY friend , Variable declaration is different than definition.
here you are initialzing a variable at the place of Declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot initialize instance variables. They are all initialized to nil or zeroes. So compiler expect a semicolon when you are writing an equal sign.

You can initialize them in init method.

Comment: I don't have a init method. Should I make one just to set the values of my variables properly?

Comment: If you want to initialize them yes. You have.

Comment: I think you don't **have to** but you can. For example you can use the `(void)viewDidLoad` method to store your init lines. Because this method is called when the view is loaded (as it's said…). For my own, I  rarely write my own init method in some viewController, except if I really have a lot of variables. In iOS, I just use the viewDidLoad method to init my variables.

Comment: This class is not a ViewController. It's just a class I implement to help me recycling some of my code.

Comment: Beside other motivations for an -init… (parameters on init, i. e.) you can make up your decision by this conclusion:

1) The RTE automatically set all ivars to representations of 0 (NULL, nil, Nil, 0, 0.0).

2) You should not set an ivar to the representation of 0 because of 1).

3) If you do not have an ivar, set to an value other then a representation of 0 (and no other init-code like registration $whereever), an -init… would be empty = useless.

The other way round: If you have to set an ivar initially to something else than an representation of 0, add an -init…

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to add an instance variable to a class extension or category which is unsupported.  *[EDIT 2013-05-12 06-11-08: ivars in class extension are supported, but not in categories.]*  As an alternative:

```
@interface UIDesign : NSObject
@end

@interface UIDesign ()

@property (nonatomic, assign) int privateInt;
@end

@implementation UIDesign

@synthesize privateInt = _privateInt;

- (void)someMethod {
    self.privateInt = 42;
}

@end
```

On the other hand, if you just want to declare an instance variable inside the implementation, just do it there:

```
@implementation UIDesign {
    int _privateInt;
}

@end
```

**EDIT:**  just noticed that you're also attempting to initialize instance variables in the declaration which is also unsupported.  So:

```
@interface UIDesign : NSObject
@end

@implementation UIDesign {
    NSString *_test;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if( !self ) return nil;

    _test = @"Foo";

    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: I don't have a init method. Should I make one just to set the values of my variables properly?

Comment: It depends.  If the proper functioning of your class depends on an initial value for an ivar, then yes.

Comment: synthesizing is no longer necessary

Comment: Adding Ivars in a class extension is supported.

Comment: Yes, of course.  My bad.  In class extensions, but not categories.  Edited.